# How to return a code value into a variable

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have the below case in my report:

Receivable: `RunningValue(Fields!Receivable.Value,SUM,Nothing)`

Production: `code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))`

Rec/Prod: Receivable / Production.

```
Public Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
    Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
    suma = 0
    ct = 0
    For Each item As Object In items
        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
        ct += 1
    Next

    If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

The problem is for Rec/Prod, if prod = 0 i receive error.

Ive tried to put the below condition:

```
IIF(code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))=0,0,RunningValue(Fields!Receivable.Value,SUM,Nothing)/(code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))))
```

but since in the false condition i am recalling code.SumLookup in order to get the value in regetting 0 for production and consiquently i get error for Rec/Prod.

how can i call code.sumlookup on time only and save its value into a variable so i dont need to call it everytime i need to check the value.

or if there any other solution please advise.

Comment: Your question is lacking an introduction, interpunction, and general flow. Could you please review and edit your question so it's a bit easier (and more pleasant) to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try to add  textbox into the report and setting it's value to your Production expression. I named the textbox "Production" and i refer to that value using the syntax ReportItems!Production.Value, but it also gave the same error.

The solution i found is the below:

For the below function, report builder will evaluate all parts of the function. This means that even though your function takes into account “if prod=0” it still goes on to do the Rec/Prod evaluation and so errors. Please try this formula, the extra ‘IF’ allows the function to evaluate without error.

```
IIF(code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))=0,0,RunningValue(Fields!Receivable.Value,SUM,Nothing)/IIF(code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))=0,1, code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a textbox into the report and setting it's value to your Production expression. If you named the textbox "Production" then you can refer to that value using the syntax ReportItems!Production.Value.